# Is it possible to make your own Q-Thruster?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

Is it possible to make a homemade Q-Thruster assuming you cover all the safety requirements? I know the one made by (http://cannae.com/) uses a magnetron and resonate cavity to bounce the microwaves, and honestly seems easy to build. All I would need is to get the magnetron from a microwave and build a resonate cavity chamber to bounce the microwaves.

Comment: Are you talking about the [Quantum vacuum plasma thruster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_vacuum_plasma_thruster)?  If so, I doubt anyone here is going to have expertise in building one since their principle of operation is still a topic of heated debate.

Comment: What's a "Q-Thruster"?  Without difining the terms you are using, this is a non-question.

Comment: @ChrisMueller Judging by the link, he's talking about [a radio frequency resonant cavity thruster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EmDrive#Cannae_drive).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could.

But if it failed to work in the same manner that theirs reportedly did, you'd be in trouble, as NASA would not test it for you :-). If yours DID work then NASA may be interested.

ie there was considerable debate as to whether it really works - despite it having "been shown" to do so by NASA testing. Updates referenced below indicate that NASA is still working on it, albeit with a limited budget, and that results are still positive, as of February this year (2015).

If yours failed to work you'd be on your own.
However, it's conceivable that NASA and others MAY be willing to provide guidance.
(This is an alteration of my initial more negative conclusion).

---

Good Wikipedia overview supplied by **Greg Mueller** [**Quantum vaccuum plasma thruster**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_vacuum_plasma_thruster)

Excellent summary of NASA results with some pictures and charts - February 6th 2015.
[**Update on EMDrive work at NASA Eagleworks**](http://nextbigfuture.com/2015/02/update-on-emdrive-work-at-nasa.html) - some good links

[**Online copy of NASA report claiming US government copyright waiver**](http://www.libertariannews.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/AnomalousThrustProductionFromanRFTestDevice-BradyEtAl.pdf)

[NASA test summary - 2013](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20140006052.pdf)

NASA paper abstract [Anomalous Thrust Production from an RF Test Device Measured on a Low-Thrust Torsion Pendulum](http://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.2014-4029) - for $ paper.

---

Reported results:

[image]

From this:

[image]

Comment: If you're expecting thrusts in the uN range, even if it does work you may have problems measuring anything.